# How find the polynomial whose roots are $\frac{{a^2 }} {{2a^2 + bc}},\frac{{b^2 }} {{2b^2 + ca}},\frac{{c^2 }} {{2c^2 + ab}}$?

Tags: polynomials

a,b,c are the roots of the polynomial $x^3 - (a + b + c)x^2 + (ab + bc + ca)x - abc$.
How find the polynomial whose roots are $\frac{{a^2 }} {{2a^2 + bc}},\frac{{b^2 }} {{2b^2 + ca}},\frac{{c^2 }} {{2c^2 + ab}}$?

I think that this polynomial has the form $y ^{3}-(a+b+c)y ^{2}+(ab+bc+ac)y-abc$ where $y=???$ contains $x,a,b,c $. But how to do it?

Comment: This question (literally!) answers itself. The first sentence shows how to construct a polynomial with given arbitrary roots. So simply take the roots you are given, and plug them into that formula. If it helps, you can give the variables different names in the formula, like $A$, $B$, and $C$, to avoid confusion with the $a,b$ and $c$ in the expressions for the roots themselves.

Comment: I tried, but unfortunately, I do not know how to do that.

Comment: I'm not sure you and I are talking about the same thing. The first sentence says that the polynomial $x^3-(A+B+C)x^2+(AB+BC+CA)x-ABC$ has roots $A$, $B$, and $C$. Now all we must do is set $A=\frac{a^2}{2a^2+bc}$ and similarly for $B$ and $C$, do as much simplification as we can stand, and we're done. As for the form you describe, I can't imagine a priori why this would be the case: what makes you think that the polynomial has this form?

Comment: Because I solved another problem where you had to write in this form.

Answer (score 2):

Just as  Eric Stucky commeneted, the answer in inside the question. The polynomial you look for is $$\left(y-\frac{b^2}{a c+2 b^2}\right) \left(y-\frac{a^2}{2 a^2+b c}\right)
   \left(y-\frac{c^2}{a b+2 c^2}\right)$$ which can simplify to $$\left(b c y +a^2 (2 y-1)\right) \left(a c y+b^2 (2 y-1)\right) \left(a b y+c^2 (2
   y-1)\right)$$ Now, the expansion is not very nice and writing it as $$Ay^3+By^2+Cy+D$$ we find $$D=-a^2 b^2 c^2$$ $$C=a^3 b^3+a^3 c^3+b^3 c^3+6 a^2 b^2 c^2$$ $$B=-a^4 b c-4 a^3 b^3-4 a^3 c^3-12 a^2 b^2 c^2-a b^4 c-a b c^4-4 b^3 c^3$$ $$A=2 a^4 b c+4 a^3 b^3+4 a^3 c^3+9 a^2 b^2 c^2+2 a b^4 c+2 a b c^4+4 b^3 c^3$$

Comment: Look problem: $\alpha ,\beta ,\gamma$ be the roots of $ x^3 + px^2 + qx + r = 0$

 find the polynomial whose roots are $ \alpha  -\frac{1}{{\beta \gamma }},\beta  - \frac{1}
{{\lambda \alpha }},\gamma  - \frac{1}{{\alpha \beta }}$

Comment: Solution: If $ x^{3} + px^{2} + qx + r = 0$ has roots $ \alpha ,\beta ,\gamma$, then $ -r=\alpha\beta\gamma$, $ -r-1=\alpha\beta\gamma-1$
$ (-rx)^3 + p(-rx)^2 + q(-rx) + r = 0$ has roots $ \frac {1}{\alpha\beta}, \frac {1}{\beta\gamma}, \frac {1}{\gamma\alpha}$
$ \left(\frac {rx}{r + 1}\right)^3 + p\left(\frac {rx}{r + 1}\right)^2 + q\left(\frac {rx}{r + 1}\right) + r = 0$ has roots $ \frac {\alpha\beta\gamma - 1}{\alpha\beta}, \frac {\alpha\beta\gamma - 1}{\beta\gamma}, \frac {\alpha\beta\gamma - 1}{\gamma\alpha}$

Answer (score 0):

If $\displaystyle x^3-Px^2+Qx-R=0, a^3=Pa^2-Qa+R$

If $\displaystyle y=\frac{a^2}{2a^2+bc},y=\frac{a^3}{2a^3+abc}=\frac{a^3}{2a^3+R}\iff a^3=\frac{Ry}{1-2y}$

We have  $\displaystyle a^3-R=Pa^2-Qa,$

Cubing we get,  $\displaystyle(a^3-R)^3=(Pa^2-Qa)^3$

$\displaystyle\left(a^3-R\right)^3=P^3(a^3)^2-Q^3(a^3)-3PQ (a^3)(a^3-R)$

Replace $a^3$ with $\dfrac{Ry}{1-2y}$

Comment: So how will look  eventually this polynomial?

Comment: @piteer, $$y^3-P'y^2+Q'y-R'=0$$